# In what ways could this React code be improved?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, promise, react-component, code-structure

I am brand new to React and only semi familiar with JS. I starting making an application using React/Flask/Mongodb, but I am getting tripped up on some of the best way to structure my function calls/variable sets/renders. I have done my research enough to get this component working, but I feel like it's clunky and there is a better way. Essentially, I am trying to retrieve results from my DB for an item wishlist and show their attributes on screen. I have struggled with the returns from Promises as well variable scope/placement in order to render my returned lists. Ideally, I would return my list from the DB and have that stored without modification so I can create a list that actually shows on the UI that can be changed due to filters. Let me know if I posted this incorrectly.

```
    Wishlist.js

    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import Apis from './apis'
    class Wishlist extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: "",
        quantity: 0,
        baselink: "",
        filter: "Default",
        wishes: [],
        wishesToShow: [],
        loading: 'initial'
    };

    this.GetWishesList = this.GetWishesList.bind(this);
    this.ShowWishes = this.ShowWishes.bind(this);
    this.HandleFilterChange = this.HandleFilterChange.bind(this);

}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    this.GetWishesList();

}

ShowWishes() {
    const uiWishes = this.state.wishesToShow
    return (
        < div >
            {
                uiWishes == null ? null :
                    uiWishes.map(({ name, quantity, cost, description, category, link }) => (
                        <div className='wish' key={cost}>
                            <div className="wishatt">Category: {category}</div>
                            <div className="wishatt">Item name: {name}</div>
                            <div className="wishatt">Description: {description}</div>
                            <div className="wishatt">Cost: {cost}</div>
                            <a className="wishatt" href={link}>Link: {link}</a>
                            <div className="wishatt">Quantity: {quantity}</div>
                        </div>
                    ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}

HandleFilterChange = (e) => {
    const wishcheck = this.state.wishes
    const value = e.target.value;

    for (var i = wishcheck.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (wishcheck[i].category !== value) {
            wishcheck.splice(i, 1);
        }
        if (wishcheck[i] != null) { console.log(wishcheck[i].category); }
    }
    this.setState({ filter: value, wishesToShow: wishcheck });
}

GetWishesList() {
    Apis.GetWishes().then(function (response) { return response; }).then(data => {
        this.setState({ wishes: data.data, wishesToShow: data.data, loading: 'false' });
    })

}

render() {
    if (this.state.loading === 'initial') {
        return <h2 className="content">Initializing...</h2>;
    }

    if (this.state.loading === 'true') {
        return <h2 className="content">Loading...</h2>;
    }

    const mywishes = this.ShowWishes();

    return (
        <div className="contentwrapper">
            <div className="contentBanner"><h1 className="wishTitle">Wishes:</h1> <label>
                <p className="bannerFilter">Category</p>
                <select name="category" value={this.state.filter} onChange={this.HandleFilterChange}>
                    <option value="default">Default</option>
                    <option value="camping">Camping</option>
                    <option value="hendrix">Hendrix</option>
                    <option value="decor">Decor</option>
                </select>
            </label></div>
            <div className="content"><div>{mywishes}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
    }
    export default Wishlist;
```

```
Apis.js

import axios from 'axios';


export default class Apis {

    static InsertWish(body) {
        console.log(body)
        return axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/submitwish`, body)
            .then(response => response)
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }

    static GetWishes() {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getwishlists`)
            .then(response => response)
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use async-await instead of promise chaining. 2) Look into migrating to functional components instead of using class components like you are now. 3) You are importing hooks which you are not using (and also aren't compatible with class components). 4) Not necessarily wrong, but I'm personally not a big fan of having functions that are responsible for part of the rendering of the component (eg. `ShowWishes()`) it's in, to me it adds unnecessary cognitive complexion to keep track of all the functions, but this is preference

Answer (score 1):

I would also clean up the JSX in Wishlist.js.

```
return (
        <div className="contentwrapper">
            <div className="contentBanner">
              <h1 className="wishTitle">Wishes:</h1> 
              <label>
                <p className="bannerFilter">Category</p>
                <select 
                  name="category" 
                  value={this.state.filter} 
                  onChange={this.HandleFilterChange}>
                   <option value="default">Default</option>
                   <option value="camping">Camping</option>
                   <option value="hendrix">Hendrix</option>
                   <option value="decor">Decor</option>
                </select>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
              {mywishes}
            </div>
        </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import useEffect or useState because you're not using functional components.

So I would change line 1 in Wishlist.js—

from

**import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';**

to

**import React from 'react';**

Comment: I would change it to: import { useEffect, useState, Component  } from 'react'; No need to import React in version ^17.

Comment: Why would you import useEffect or useState when you're not going to be using either?

Comment: It is an example, I did not check the code. Only saw his React.Component